# What does '_' stands for in Razor?

Tags: c#, lambda

What does ' _ ' stands for in the below code? I was trying the new scaffolding and it generates the below code. However, I'm not sure what ' _ ' used for.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(_ => item.User).ToString()
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not Razor specific. And that it's a `_` isn't significant either. It's just a valid identifier for a parameter of a lambda.

`identifier => function` is the form of a single parameter lambda. And `_` happens to be a valid identifier. In this case the author most likely wants to indicate that the parameter doesn't matter to him, using the name `_`.

`_ => item.User` means define a one parameter function that maps any parameter to `item.User`.

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

[`=>` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Comment: The choice of `_` likely stems from the ML family of languages, where `_` is a special symbol used to match any argument and ignore it.